# how to merge the arrays

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays shown below, if i want `array[0]` and `array[1]` of `ht_cat_name` is same. So `ht_category` is common for 2 arrays. so ht_category based from merge ht_amenity_name.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ht_amenity_id] => 1
            [ht_amenity_name] => Central Air Conditioning
            [ht_category] => 1
            [ht_cat_name] => General
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ht_amenity_id] => 2
            [ht_amenity_name] => Facilities for disabled guests
            [ht_category] => 1
             [ht_cat_name] => General
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ht_amenity_id] => 3
            [ht_amenity_name] => Climate control
            [ht_category] => 2
            [ht_cat_name] => Services
        )
)
```

I want to merge like this the amenities name .

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ht_amenity_id][0] => 1 
            [ht_amenity_id][1] => 2
            [ht_amenity_name][0] => Central Air Conditioning
            [ht_amenity_name][1] => Facilities for disabled guests
            [ht_category] => 1
            [ht_cat_name] => General
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ht_amenity_id] => 3
            [ht_amenity_name] => Climate control
            [ht_category] => 2
            [ht_cat_name] => Services
        )

)
```

Comment: Where is the code which you tried? Please add the code which you tried for this....

Comment: $amen=DB::select("SELECT `h`.`ht_amenity_id`,`h`.`ht_amenity_name`,`h`.`ht_category`,`a`.`ht_cat_name` FROM `abserve_hotel_amenities`  as `h` JOIN  abserve_hotel_categories as `a` ON `a`.`ht_cat_id` =`h`.`ht_category`");

   $am=array();
   foreach ($amen as $key => $value) {
   $am[]=(get_object_vars($value));
   }

   $user=array();
   foreach ($hotelroom as $key => $value) {
   $user[]=(get_object_vars($value));
   }

Comment: sry,                                                                                                                     $amen=DB::select("SELECT `h`.`ht_amenity_id`,`h`.`ht_amenity_name`,`h`.`ht_category`,`a`.`ht_cat_name` FROM `abserve_hotel_amenities`  as `h` JOIN  abserve_hotel_categories as `a` ON `a`.`ht_cat_id` =`h`.`ht_category`");

   $am=array();
   foreach ($amen as $key => $value) {
   $am[]=(get_object_vars($value));
   }

   $user=array();
   foreach ($hotelroom as $key => $value) {
   $user[]=(get_object_vars($value));
   }

Comment: Please do not post code in comments - Always add it to your question. It is unreadable and you may want to edit it anyway. Also, people don't have to read all your comments to find out all the relevant information about your question. Have I mentioned it is unreadable? You can delete your own comments afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change how you get the data (i.e. it comes from an API or you can't modify the SQL query) your best bet would be a collection pipeline library (the pure PHP solution would be two nested foreaches which i don't like much.

This should work for you (written using [Knapsack](https://dusankasan.github.io/Knapsack/)):

```
$data = [
    [
        "ht_amenity_id" => 1,
        "ht_amenity_name" => "Central Air Conditioning",
        "ht_category" => 1,
        "ht_cat_name" => "General",
    ],

    [
        "ht_amenity_id" => 2,
        "ht_amenity_name" => "Facilities for disabled guests",
        "ht_category" => 1,
        "ht_cat_name" => "General",
    ],

    [
        "ht_amenity_id" => 3,
        "ht_amenity_name" => "Climate control",
        "ht_category" => 2,
        "ht_cat_name" => "Services",
    ]
];

$transformed = Collection::from($data)
    ->groupByKey('ht_category')
    ->map(function (Collection $category, $categoryId) {
        return [
            "ht_amenity_id" => $category->extract('ht_amenity_id')->toArray(),
            "ht_amenity_name" => $category->extract('ht_amenity_name')->toArray(),
            "ht_category" => $categoryId,
            "ht_cat_name" => $category->extract('ht_cat_name')->first(),
        ];
    })
    ->toArray();
```

Collection pipeline libraries:

- https://dusankasan.github.io/Knapsack/
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections
- http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html